# Rename column names programatically in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, etl

I have an excel file, which has to be cleaned in SSIS. 
One of the tasks is to rename the column names from their default values of F1, F2.... Total columns are currently 95 and there are other such large excel files. I am looking for a way to rename these column names. [Please see the image. It is cumbersome to change names from the drag-drop menu and is not maintainable IMHO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDhFH.png)

[image]

Comment: SSIS will use column headers if they are available. Just add them if they are missing. You can create a test file with headers to create the source, then change the target to the actual file

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. But I would like to rename the column names in a programatic manner. Not through a menu

Comment: Does the Excel file have headers or no? If it doesn't open it and insert a line with the headers you want above the data. Use that file during design.

Comment: It doesn't have headers. I delete the headers that the client supplies. Later I want to populate the top header row with column names as we desire

Comment: if you rename something programmatically how would SSIS know how to map it?  You can do it after import to staging, you can setup the flat file connection with the names you want by using an Excel template that has the appropriate number of columns and the headers you want.  You could leave the client supplied headers in if they would be better than F1, F2 etc. and map to whatever the column name you want at your destination....SSIS is rigid in determining mapping, data types, column names etc.

Comment: You can script the entire import in an SSIS task but then you might as well use any thing to do it such as powershell, console program, etc.  As it won't utilize the power of SSIS data flow.